# change mouse cursor to a wait icon and prevent the user from clicking on any controls

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

In my Silverlight MVVM application, after making a web service call, I'd like to change my cursor to a wait icon and prevent the user from clicking on any controls on the screen.

Currently I have used Busy Indicator to prevent clicking on any control on the screen.

Please Help...!!

Comment: What is the solution you applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controls are in a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you can play with the [`IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.control.isenabled%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

**Msdn :**

> When IsEnabled is **false**, a control cannot have focus or receive input
>   events, such as [MouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). A control inherits the IsEnabled
>   property from its parent control. For example, if a control that
>   contains a button has IsEnabled set to **false**, the button's IsEnabled
>   property is also **false**.

The busy indicator is already using this principle, provided it is your parent controls :

**Wrong :**

```
<Grid>
    <!-- My content -->
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator></toolkit:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

**Right :**

```
<Grid>
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator>
        <!-- My content -->
    </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

make IsHitTestVisble of your grid Disabled

Comment: Thanks... You are right for mouse control but we can't stop keyboard control. I want to stop keyboard control also.